# How to bind events such as onchange in razor views without violating CSP

Tags: security, asp.net-core, razor, content-security-policy

In an effort to improve security, I've added this response header in middleware.`content-security-policy: default-src 'self'`.

And in a razor partial view I have a SELECT element with `onchange="this.form.submit()`

```
<div class="dropdown-item text-dark">
    <form id="selectLanguage" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form"
            asp-controller="Home"
            asp-action="PersistLanguage" 
            asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">
        <select name="culture" onchange="this.form.submit()"
                asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Consequently, the browser reports the following.

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
>   data:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or
>   a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note
>   also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback.
>
> (Unknown) ListPicker._handleMouseUp

Loosening up the policy resolves it, but doing so is not recommended: `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`.

What is the right way to bind events such as onchange in razor partial views without violating the CSP inline script constraint?

Answer (score 3):

You can write some code like this in the script file.

```
$(function(){
    $("#culture").change(function(){
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anuraj.  I agree that sort of event binding is necessary to satisfy CSP. So you're saying move ALL event bindings to a separate js file (or multiple files), and add script refs pointing to those files, from the views? I've also subsequently tried the approach of doing the binding in a small embedded script block directly after the <select> declaration, but that required implementing nonce to satisfy the CSP. More effort but the upside is a view that is more intuitive to maintain because the binding logic is adjacent to the HTML element instead of 'somewhere else'.

Comment: There is asp.net core middle ware available, which helps to implement CSP in apps. Please check out that as well. Also instead of using vanilla JavaScript. Try to use Angular if possible, in which csp support is available.

Comment: Yeah I usually use Angular but in this case am limited to Razor. Decision not within my control.

Comment: If you're using vanila javascript - move the inline scripts to files is the easy way.